# Why is $.ajax undefined when using jQuery on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a module that is supposed to run on the client, but I'm testing it on Node.js, so I'd like to make `$.ajax` to work.

I installed `jQuery` on the project:

```
$ npm install jQuery
```

Then I'm doing this:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
console.log($.ajax); // undefined
```

`$.ajax` is undefined.

It makes a bit of sense for me because `ajax` is static and I think the result of `require("jquery")` would be the equivalent of `$.fn` in the browser.

How do I use `$.ajax` on node?

Comment: It `var $ = require("jQuery");` not `var $ = require("jquery");`

Comment: `$.ajax()` in a browser uses the XMLHttpRequest object in the browser to do its networking.   That object does not exist in node.js so unless some sort of node-specific support for `$.ajax()` was installed, it wouldn't be there.

Comment: why would you use jQuery on node?

Comment: There is no ajax method in jquery package for nodejs. [For more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184300/why-is-there-no-ajax-method-in-jquery-package-for-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the reason from this docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#node

> For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes.

But the setup code of the docs is out of date.

The latest setup code is:

```js
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = new JSDOM("").window;
global.document = document;

var $ = require("jquery")(window);

// test
console.log("$.get:", typeof $.get);
console.log("$.ajax:", typeof $.ajax);
$.get("http://localhost:3000", data => {
  console.log(data);
});

module.exports = $;
```

Run this code, got:

```sh
$.get: function
$.ajax: function
normal
```

The `normal` text is the response from my local http server.

Dependencies versions:

```
"jsdom": "^15.2.1",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
```