# How to use jquery in node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I use node.js, Firebase Functions.
I try to implement a very simple function (in functions/index.js) that use POST method to get response from third party website:

```
exports.haveData = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    var $ = require('jquery');
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://example.com/info.html',
            data: {
                "id": data.id
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Success !!");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error !!");
            }
        }
    );

    return "Function ended";
});
```

But I have error code:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at /workspace/index.js:35:7
    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I cannot figure out what can be the problem... :(

Comment: There are many other better libraries than jquery that can be used for making HTTP requests in nodejs.

Comment: If you want to do http request in node use either api provided directly by node [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) or [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) or use  a module like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $.ajax undefined when using jQuery on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191339/why-is-ajax-undefined-when-using-jquery-on-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not ideally suited for Node.js as the former independently wraps and/or applies properties to browser objects, like `window` and `document`. jQuery's `ajax`, for example, takes advantage  of window.XMLHttpRequest.

In order to handle this natively you will need to either take advantage of Node's `http` package (using its `request` method) or install an NPM package that simplifies it for you. I would recommend `axios` as its API can be used by a browser or Node but there many competent options to choose from.

Node's HTTP: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Axios JS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) for the JQuery NPM Package

> For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required.
> Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by
> tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes.