# PHP and Form Handling event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create form object based on the input on of the another select/textbox of the same box. For example if the user selects "Yes"/checks  show him the textbox to input the value else do not show.

```
<form id="create_config_file" name="create_config_file" method="post">
  <table width="87%" height="220" border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Server Details</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="226">Name:</td>
        <td width="783"><input name="server_name" type="text" id="server_name" size="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>IP Address:</td>
        <td><input name="ip_address" type="text" id="ip_address" size="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Port:</td>
        <td><input name="port" type="text" id="port" size="10"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NAT:</td>
        <td><select name="NAT" id="NAT">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No" selected="selected">No</option>
        </select></td>
```

Now I need to show input box to the user, if selects YES or else no input box is displayed. How can I achieve this. I am using PHP.

I googled but looks like my search query was not good enough.

Any help is appreciated.

THANKS

Comment: I would use jquery, $('#NAT').on('change', function(){if($(this).val()=='Yes')//do something)});

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not related to your server language.
You can use your input onchange events to show or hide an item:

```
<script>

function tryme(obj) {
    if ($(obj).checked) {
        $("#my_textbox").show();
    } else {
        $("#my_textbox").show();
    }

}

</script>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="tryme(this);" />
<input type="text" id="my_textbox" />
```

If you forced to show the form again, a point in the future, you maybe have some challenge with your editing content, try loading with php or displaying dynamically using javascript.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is not need to achieve this. Because PHP is a server side scripting. You need to use Client side scripting languages like javascript to achieve this. To know more detail about client side scripting vs Server side Scripting check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270834/3049065). I used [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) which is a javascript library. I added the code below which will as you expected. But you need to learn more about javascript, jquery, php refer [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com).

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Add the Library file -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="create_config_file" name="create_config_file" method="post">
 <table width="87%" height="220" border="2" cellpadding="1"
  cellspacing="1" class="CSSTableGenerator">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Server Details</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="226">Name:</td>
    <td width="783"><input name="server_name" type="text"
     id="server_name" size="40"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>IP Address:</td>
    <td><input name="ip_address" type="text" id="ip_address" size="40"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Port:</td>
    <td><input name="port" type="text" id="port" size="10"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>NAT:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="NAT" id="NAT">
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No" selected="selected">No</option>
    </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#server_name").hide();
 $("#ip_address").hide();
 $("#port").hide();
 $("#NAT").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "Yes"){
   $("#server_name").show();
   $("#ip_address").show();
   $("#port").show();
  }else{
   $("#server_name").hide();
   $("#ip_address").hide();
   $("#port").hide();
  }
 });
});
</script>
</html>
```