# Client-side scripting javascript -language or languages

Tags: javascript, client

I have seen here a question and i wonder about it.When we write in a page we can write only in javascript in a client side scripting?Or we could write in different languages and to put where ever we wanted,at the start of the page,or in the end of the page?https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/how-scripting-languages-work/ .As i have seen this article it says it uses javascript or ajax,but as you can see on the image down of it it has "html,css and javascript".Client side scripting uses only a language or many

Comment: Hi An P.  Quick forewarning, you may get a lot of downvotes on your question since it is not asking for help on specific code.  Ultimately, browsers understand HTML, CSS, and JavaScript -- there are a lot of libraries and tools that expand/mutate these, but in the end it's all being converted to one of these three things.  AJAX is Asychronous JavaScript And XML (If I recall correctly) -- it's just a JavaScript feature that lets you query APIs -- but still JavaScript

Comment: so all together do use 1 language?Why downvotes to me ?there is a guy who isn't have a code and has a lot of votes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270648/client-side-scripting-and-server-side-scripting-languages check this please ,he hasn't code too.I just ask little further for better understanding

Comment: I don't plan on downvoting ;) just giving you a heads up if soomeone else does.

Comment: thanks you a lot :)

Comment: JavaScript is the main/most common scripting language for websites.  jQuery is built on top of JavaScript, as is Node - React - Vue - Angular ... they are all built on top of the foundation that is JavaScript.  However, knowing JavaScript doesn't mean you can instantly master tools built on top of it.  Every tool has its own learning curve.

Comment: @Doug excellent ,thank you very much :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client side scripting and Server side scripting languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270648/client-side-scripting-and-server-side-scripting-languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do client-side scripting in many languages; JavaScript is just a common one. HTML (HyperText Markup Language), CSS (Cascading Style Sheets), and JavaScript are the most common languages to do client-side work in. 
HTML gives the page its structure; CSS gives it its style, and JavaScript gives it its functionality.
You can also use JQuery and other scripting "languages" to do do the work of JavaScript, but those are just extensions/plugins/libraries of JavaScript that will get transpiled to JavaScript.

Hope this helps. Do a quick google search on client side scripting languages and pick your favorite one to use!

Comment: so the scripts can be in different languages but in the end we will have a language Javascript,right?

Comment: That's right! The other "languages" are just there to make using JavaScript more convenient.