# Execute php inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I'm trying to do is navigate to another page using a php script, so when I press the button it should change pages, but that's not what happens. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function changeScreen() {
        <?php
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: PHP script run before HTML (Javascript) output.

Comment: Think you should look over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270648/client-side-scripting-and-server-side-scripting-languages

Comment: Why don't use window.location to do this ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1